# This is one to many relational model question

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

This is a code of my sql. What's wrong with this code. The second table shows an error message.
There is no error in the first table. The error message is below.
Please find out the cause of the error.

```
***error maessage----->*** 

    mysql> create table req(
        -> rid int auto_increment not null,
        -> joinedDate datetime not null default current_timestamp(),
        -> constraint primary key(rid),
        -> constraint foreign key(fid) references friend(fid)
        -> );
   *** ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'fid' doesn't exist in table
    mysql>

    ***My SQL code.......>***

    drop database if exists new;
    create database new;

    use new;

    create table friend(
        fid int auto_increment not null,
        fname varchar(25) not null,
        tp int(3) not null,
        constraint primary key(fid)
    );

    insert into friend(fname,tp)
    values
        ('Nimal Perera',0775548754),
        ('Sandun Hashan',0755548754),
        ('Kamni wasundara',0765548754),
        ('Nuawani Sandareka',0771545704);

    select* from friend;
    desc friend;

    create table req(
        rid int auto_increment not null, 
        joinedDate datetime not null default current_timestamp(),
        constraint primary key(rid),
        constraint foreign key(fid) references friend(fid)
    );
```

Comment: You have no `fid` column in your `req` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table req(
   rid int,
   fid int,
   joinedDate datetime not null default current_timestamp(),
   constraint primary key(rid),
   constraint foreign key(fid) references friend(fid)
   on delete cascade on update cascade
   );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation what you have changed and why. Your answer will only lead to copy and pasting it without understanding what actually makes the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
drop database if exists new;
    create database new;

    use new;

    create table friend(
        fid int auto_increment not null,
        fname varchar(25) not null,
        tp int(3) not null,
        constraint primary key(fid)
    );

    insert into friend(fname,tp)
    values
        ('Nimal Perera',0775548754),
        ('Sandun Hashan',0755548754),
        ('Kamni wasundara',0765548754),
        ('Nuawani Sandareka',0771545704);

    select* from friend;
    desc friend;

    create table req(
        fid int,
        rid int auto_increment not null, 
        joinedDate datetime not null default current_timestamp(),
        constraint primary key(rid),
        constraint foreign key(fid) references friend(fid)
    );

    select* from req;
    desc req;
```

Output----->

```
+-----+-------------------+-----------+
| fid | fname             | tp        |
+-----+-------------------+-----------+
|   1 | Nimal Perera      | 775548754 |
|   2 | Sandun Hashan     | 755548754 |
|   3 | Kamni wasundara   | 765548754 |
|   4 | Nuawani Sandareka | 771545704 |
+-----+-------------------+-----------+

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fid   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tp    | int(3)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Empty set (0.00 sec)

+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| fid        | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| rid        | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| joinedDate | datetime | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Please don't just dump code, explain why it is answering the question. [answer]